# When is a differential choke preferred to an LC filter and vice versa?

Tags: passive-filter

Both single LC and differential choke are used for attenuating differential mode noise.

I only know that LC filter has resonance issues. Is that the only reason a differential choke is preferred?

Can a differential choke be considered as a powerful inductor and be used as used in an LC filter?

I cannot find information about such comparison. Can you give two scenarios where one is preferred to another?

Comment: Normally it’s frequency dependent. Somewhere in the ~30 MHz region differential filters have less impact and above it you end up with common mode instead. What frequency are you thinking about? Have you considered CLC? Have you considered cheating by winding your CM filter slightly differential?

Comment: Show both circuits side by side so there is no ambibuity in your question please.